# add library to new package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im working on mpu6050 package, i have a library which is work well outside ROS, but i have a problem to make the package, i wrote a node and i added the headers an and the cpp files to include directory in my package  , when i do catkin_make, the node can't see the headers , thats what i got:

```
/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/src/mpu6050/src/mpu6050_node.cpp:12:21: fatal error: mpu6050.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
mpu6050/CMakeFiles/mpu6050_node.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'mpu6050/CMakeFiles/mpu6050_node.dir/src/mpu6050_node.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [mpu6050/CMakeFiles/mpu6050_node.dir/src/mpu6050_node.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:379: recipe for target 'mpu6050/CMakeFiles/mpu6050_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [mpu6050/CMakeFiles/mpu6050_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

i did changes to my CMakeList.txt as questions before me but nothing happened

any ideas ??
thank u in advance.

---

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(mpu6050)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS rosconsole roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs)

catkin_package( INCLUDE_DIRS include LIBRARIES mpu6050 CATKIN_DEPENDS rosconsole roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs )

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} src/mpu6050/include/mpu6050 )

add_library(mpu6050 include/${PROJECT_NAME}/mpu6050.cpp include/${PROJECT_NAME}/I2Cdev.cpp ) 

add_executable(mpu6050_node src/mpu6050/src/mpu6050_node.cpp )
add_dependencies(mpu6050_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}) 

target_link_libraries(mpu6050_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )

install(TARGETS mpu6050 mpu6050_node
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/ 
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247034/add-library-to-new-package/) by [sayed](https://answers.ros.org/users/28413/sayed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-02**:
maybe post your `CMakeLists` then?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-04**:
Don't post edits as answers. There is an edit button below you question.
Use the formatted text button for code (the one with 1s and 0s).

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-04**:
Can you link to github or whatever hoster? This would make live easier.

Otherwise: Post the line where you include the file, as well as the layout of your package (which file is where). Where is the `mpu6050.h` located?

Please **edit** your question

**Comment by [sayed](https://answers.ros.org/users/28413/sayed/) on 2016-11-04**:
i'll link it.
mpu6050.h is in include directory

**Comment by [sayed](https://answers.ros.org/users/28413/sayed/) on 2016-11-04**:
here the CMakeList
https://github.com/AhmedElsayedHamouda/first.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, your workspace setup is crooked (at least to the `CMakeLists.txt` and we do have nothing else).

I see the following paths:

- `src/mpu6050/include/mpu6050` -> this seems like include files, but they are in `src`?
- `include/mpu6050` -> but there are `.cpp` files?
- `src/mpu6050/src/mpu6050_node.cpp` -> this is the file with the error
- `include` -> this is where you say the `mpu6050.h` is?

And this is all in the following directory:
`/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/src/mpu6050/src/mpu6050_node.cpp`?

So my next question is: Where is your `CMakeLists.txt`?  It seems to me you have the `CMakeLists.txt` directly in `catkin_ws` which is just wrong.

Best put the full workspace on github, not only the `CMakeLists.txt` so that we can try to reproduce.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sayed](https://answers.ros.org/users/28413/sayed/) on 2016-11-04**:
thankx for replying ,, i'll put the ws on git hub, i dont use it much, it'll take a while

**Comment by [sayed](https://answers.ros.org/users/28413/sayed/) on 2016-11-05**:
https://github.com/AhmedElsayedHamouda/imu.git

this is the whole WS .. i hope u reply and help me .. thankx in advance

**Comment by [sayed](https://answers.ros.org/users/28413/sayed/) on 2016-11-05**:
in this link, the last version of CMakeList, after catkin_make, ros can read the mpu6050.h but it said that it has no members "the methods" like that iam using in the node file

**Comment by [sayed](https://answers.ros.org/users/28413/sayed/) on 2016-11-05**:
i guess the linking is good, but something wrong with my libraries